# localStorage, options data in selectmenu disappear when changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have this code that writes entered phone numbers into defined options of a selectmenu, the problem is when i go back or quit the app the data are deleted and the list is empty. I can't find out why and how to fix this...

```
    var flag_beneficiary_account_number=false;
     var beneficiary_account_number;
if ( $('#beneficiary_number').val().length > 2 ) {
    beneficiary_account_number=$('#beneficiary_number').val(); 
    flag_beneficiary_account_number=true;
} else {
    beneficiary_account_number = $('#Beneficiary_number_select').find(":selected").html();
    flag_beneficiary_account_number=false;
}

if(flag_beneficiary_account_number){

    if(localStorage.getItem("Beneficiary_number_select1")!=beneficiary_account_number &&
        localStorage.getItem("Beneficiary_number_select2")!=beneficiary_account_number &&
        localStorage.getItem("Beneficiary_number_select3")!=beneficiary_account_number){

   var select_counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("select-counter"));
        var select_option = select_counter%3;
        select_counter = select_counter+1;
        localStorage.setItem("select-counter",select_counter);

        switch  (select_option){
            case 0:
                localStorage.setItem("Beneficiary_number_select1",beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select1').val(beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select1').html(beneficiary_account_number);
                break;
            case 1:
                localStorage.setItem("Beneficiary_number_select2",beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select2').val(beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select2').html(beneficiary_account_number);
                break;
            case 2:
                localStorage.setItem("Beneficiary_number_select3",beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select3').val(beneficiary_account_number);
                $('#Beneficiary_number_select3').html(beneficiary_account_number);
                break;

            default:
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was editing your question when you finally added the `cordova` tag. Things became clear so you need to remember that in cordova, to get the localStorage to work, use it this way

```
   // To store
   window.localStorage.setItem("Beneficiary_number_select2", beneficiary_account_number);

   //and to access the value, use
  window.localStorage.localStorage
      .getItem("Beneficiary_number_select2");
```

instead `localStorage.getItem("Beneficiary_number_select2")`

Comment: but i use the localStorage everywhere else in this project and it works fine, anyways i'll try to add "window"

Comment: according to your code, localstorage will not be populated if ` $('#beneficiary_number').val().length > 2 ` returns false!

Comment: it's not working, when i press back and reopen the page the list is still empty...